# How do I decode a silk file in a Linux environment and convert it to a PCM / WAV format

Tags: python, perl, audio, decoding

I am looking for information on how to decode a .silk file in a Linux environment and convert it to a PCM / WAV format.

http://154.66.113.178/ - this is a link to the original .silk file that I tried to decode and convert to .wav file. But the audio is inaudible.

I tried to convert it by following the steps on this link that I found

https://kronopath.net/blog/extracting-audio-messages-from-wechat/

But it was a failed attempt as the .wav file was inaudible.

So essentially the way I tried to convert it didn't work - the .wav file is unusable , I don't know how to convert the .silk file to something that is audible.

Comment: What is the link? Most people will not click on that without knowing what it is.

Comment: Apologies , I am new to this ,  meant no offense

Comment: How did you convert the file? That information ought to be in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need libav-tools first, to have a toy which translates from old opus to pcm.

```
apt install libav-tools

avconv -i name.silk name.wav
```

there are more params useable, your choice!

you can call it in perl:

```
system('avconv -i name.silk name.wav');
```